# Reset Class Instance Variables via Method

Tags: php

Does anyone know how to reset the instance variables via a class method. Something like this:

```
class someClass 
{
    var $var1 = '';
    var $var2 = TRUE;

    function someMethod() 
    { 
        [...]
        // this method will alter the class variables
    }

    function reset()
    {
        // is it possible to reset all class variables from here?
    }
}

$test = new someClass();
$test->someMethod();
echo $test->var1;

$test->reset();
$test->someMethod();
```

I know I could simply do $test2 = new SomeClass() BUT I am particularly looking for a way to reset the instance (and its variables) via a method.

Is that possible at all???

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Great first question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use reflection to achieve this, for instance using `get_class_vars`:

```
foreach (get_class_vars(get_class($this)) as $name => $default) 
  $this -> $name = $default;
```

This is not entirely robust, it breaks on non-public variables (which `get_class_vars` does not read) and it will not touch base class variables.

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for. thanks!! can you explain what you mean by "not touch base class vars"?

Comment: Victor Nicollet means the variables that are defined in the parent class. You could declare a class as `class B extends A {}`; `A` would be the base, or parent class.

Comment: okay. so that means that
$test = new A();
$test->reset();
would work, whereas
$test = new B();
$test->reset(); 
wouldnt. Right?

Comment: Right. You could replace `get_class($this)` by a constant `'A'` if you were afraid of this happening.

Comment: actually this won't apply to my code. but it's good to know! :)

Answer (score -1):

Sure, the method itself could assign explicit values to the properties.

```
public function reset()
{
  $this->someString  = "original";
  $this->someInteger = 0;
}
```

#### $this->SetInitialState() from Constructor

Just as another idea, you could have a method that sets the default values itself, and is called from within the constructor. You could then call it at any point later as well.

```
<?php

  class MyClass {
    private $var;
    function __construct()     { $this->setInitialState(); }
    function setInitialState() { $this->var = "Hello World"; }
    function changeVar($val)   { $this->var = $val; }
    function showVar()         { print $this->var; }
  }

  $myObj = new MyClass();
  $myObj->showVar(); // Show default value
  $myObj->changeVar("New Value"); // Changes value
  $myObj->showVar(); // Shows new value
  $myObj->setInitialState(); // Restores default value
  $myObj->showVar(); // Shows restored value

?>
```

Comment: that's what I am doing right now. but since there's a LOT of properties in the class I thought there might be an easier solution to this...

Comment: Frank, what about calling `reset()` from the Constructor to set the initial state?

Comment: wouldn't really make a difference, would it?

Comment: Sure it would. The `__construct()` method would call `$this->setInitialState()` which sets the object properties to their default state. You can modify them with `$this->someMethod()`, and restore them with `$this->setInitialState()`.

Comment: sure. but it doesn't help rewriting all the vars in the setInititalState() method

Comment: Frank, you're going to have to have them all written someplace. What I'm suggesting is moving that task into the `setInitialState()` method, as opposed to immediately within your class.

Comment: that's what i have right now. but since i need to declare all these vars anyway I wanted to prevent writing all of these vars in the reset (or init) once again. i really like the get_class_vars() method victor suggested. that's more of what I was looking for. but thanks so much for your detailed help!

Comment: Frank, you move all of your declared values into the method, so they aren't redundant.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you could write reset() like:

```
function reset()
{
    $this->var1 = array();
    $this->var2 = TRUE;
}
```

You want to be careful because calling new someClass() will get you an entirely new instance of the class completely unrelated to the original.

Comment: see above. that's what i am doing right now. but since there are 20+ properties it just seems redundant to do this. i thought maybe there's a php function or some kind of other trick for this...

Answer (score -1):

this could be easy done;

```
public function reset()
{
    unset($this);
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't reset any properties of the object.

Comment: then you should try unset(get_class_methods($this));

Comment: actualy php resets all object properties if the object is no more needed, try __destruct() put all your cleaning stuff there

Comment: since i want to reset them to the initial state unset wouldn't work (unless the initial state would be invoked by some method via the constructor)